# Loading Excel tables into data model - what is the best practise?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery, m

In terms of efficiency of getting tables into Power Pivot...

Should I go load into Power Query and then into data model, or should I load straight to data model using "linked tables" - baring in mind, these are primarily used as look up table and not combined joined etc

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to go through Power Query.  This always gives you the chance to filter or otherwise change the input data, without trashing your modelling work.

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciated.